# isotope jquery same layout as on demo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I've downloaded isotope and tried to achieve the same animate effect the demo below uses:
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/elements-complete.html

It seems what I get is an accordion like animation from top left towards bottom right which I do not want, instead I'd like to see the containers "find" their new position as if these were floating around the wrapper. Just like on the demo, it looks as these float from everywhere to everywhere - not an accordion like animation - which is all I achieve.

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try to see the sourcecode of the page? It seems that your answer is there.

Answer (score 0):

Apply Isotope's shuffle method

```
$container.isotope('shuffle');
```